# Powershell, replace string line by line in a textfile

Tags: powershell

I have a file called "file123624.TXT" that contains this information:

```
FKHOGU1100;;;;;;;;;;;;;randomdata;1;0;2;1234
YJKMRI1101;;;;;;;;;;;;;randomdata;1;0;2;1234
FWPCYY1113;GV;randomdata;5;;;;;;;6018;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
VOBYTM1100;;;;;;;;;;;;;randomdata;1;0;2;1234
ZSOKHW1160;GV;randomdata;53;;;;;;;7353;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
YCHQHS1123;GV;randomdata;4;;;;;;;5063;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
YXRCZO1105;GV;randomdata;39;;;;;;;9510;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
XVDUEM1100;GV;randomdata;14;;;;;;;9901;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
CHECKSUM;0000008
```

All i want to do is add an - after the first six characters in the file, except for the last line "CHECKSUM; 0000008"
I have made a small powershell script that almost does the trick:

```
$file = Get-Content "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\file*.txt"
foreach ($i in $file)
    {
    if($i -notmatch "CHECKSUM*")
        {$I.Insert(6,'-')}               
    }
```

This script output the lines i need to be changed, but i cant replace them line for line.
The result i want in the "file123624.txt" after running the script is this:

```
FKHOGU-1100;;;;;;;;;;;;;randomdata;1;0;2;1234
YJKMRI-1101;;;;;;;;;;;;;randomdata;1;0;2;1234
FWPCYY-1113;GV;randomdata;5;;;;;;;6012;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
VOBYTM-1100;;;;;;;;;;;;;randomdata;1;0;2;1234
ZSOKHW-1160;GV;randomdata;53;;;;;;;7653;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
YCHQHS-1123;GV;randomdata;4;;;;;;;5463;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
YXRCZO-1105;GV;randomdata;39;;;;;;;9210;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
XVDUEM-1100;GV;randomdata;14;;;;;;;9401;randomdata;GU;;1;0;2;1234
CHECKSUM;0000008
```

Any solutions or tips on this would be appreciated

Comment: You can set your `foreach` block to a variable. Then pipe the variable contents into the file after the loop completes. You need to consider an else condition so that the `checksum` line(s) can be output as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following, which utilizes the [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6) and has a similar structure to your current code.

```
$file = Get-Content file123624.TXT | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_ -notmatch '^CHECKSUM') {
        $_.Insert(6,'-')
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
}
$file | Set-Content file123624.TXT
```

Comment: And that is how you do it, it executed perfectly. Thanks!